# Printing StackExchange pages with Firefox is slow on Ubuntu, but not on Windows; why?

Tags: printing

Printing from StackExchange is very slow from Ubuntu, but normal from Windows; why? Has anyone else noticed this before?

- First, I tried printing *via* Firefox,
- I also tried printing to PDF, and then physically printing the PDF

Both were so slow that I aborted. I tried to print various Q&A's; one worked, but it also took a very long time.

Comment: In contrast to printing from *Firefox*, printing from *Chromium* (with less printing options and no preview) is normal/fast.

Comment: I've deleted the meta-question, meta questions belong on meta.askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the culprit:

in printing options (in *Firefox*), ***disable***

- <strike>***print***</strike> background colours
- <strike>***print***</strike> background images

Often, these aren't necessary, cost toner (thereby impair one's environmental footprint!), and seem to - for certain pages - massively slow down the printing process(ing).

---

see also (for general reference)

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/940802

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-printing-problems-firefox

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-print-websites?s=print&r=0&e=es&as=s